# PDI - Condition to check is the row for each csv files more than 1

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm trying to create transformation that will read all csv and then check each files if file contain more than 1 row it will continue the transformation and else it will abort the transformation.

Comment: is all the files having the same structure?

Comment: yes, it is. each category have same structure

Answer (score 0):

There is a step name "Detect empty stream", after reading all the files next step you can put and check, if file is empty then terminate the process and if not then move go forward with the process.

Comment: Well, i don't get the logic. I have try that step and also have read `https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Detect+empty+stream`. What I know is that step only check stream data from previous step is empty or not. How to make the transformation stop by using that step and abort step? I already try put `Filter row` step after check empty but that step check value in row not the row it self.

Comment: And `Detect empty stream` step will output one row if input stream is empty (ie when input stream does not contain any row). The output row will have the same fields as the input row, but all field values will be empty (null).
If the input stream is not empty it will not output anything. How can I move go forward to next step if the output is nothing?